# Disable the button even after page refresh or logout from the application

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-cookies

I have the below code and when i refresh the application the button is enabled state. I want the button to be in disabled state even after page refresh or logout from the application. Basically i need to `save the state of the button`. How can i do that?

```
//html
<div>
<input type="file" ng-disabled="false" id="id1">
</div>

//Controller
document.getElementById("id1").disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save the state which is simple solution.

Store values for on page refresh and logout

```
localStorage.setItem('isPageRefreshed', 'true'); // page refresh

localStorage.setItem('isLoggedOut', 'true'); // on logout
```

Now you can add check for button disable, like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" ng-disabled="isDisabled" id="id1">
```

JavaScript/Controller:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('isPageRefreshed') === "true") {
  $scope.isDisabled = true;
}

if(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedOut') === "true") {
  $scope.isDisabled = true;
}
```

Anytime you want to enable the button then do this `$scope.isDisabled = false;`

Comment: Hi VicJordan i tried your code snippet and it throws an error "Cannot set property disabled of null".

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach to use ng-disabled is to control it via controller.

```
<div>
<input type="file" ng-disabled="isUserLoggedIn" id="id1">
</div>
```

> Controller

```
$scope.isUserLoggedIn = this.appService.isUserLoggedIn() || false;
//returns true or false based on if user is logged In
```

> AppService

This can check localstorage as mentioned by VicJordan or whatever logic you wanted and implement.